# Hammer.js drag and drop issue, multitouch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've implemented the drag and drop algorithm from this page: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/examples/drag.html

It works fine if the mouse doesn't move too fast on the desktop, otherwise it loses track of the original picked up element and just moves the new one, which is below the current mouse position.

A Video of the problem can be seen here:
http://www.screenr.com/tIO8

I tried to change the code to this, then it works fine, but it is not able to use multiple touches for different objects at the same time.

```
            for(var t=0,len=touches.length; t<len; t++) {
                var target = $(this);
                target.css({
                    zIndex: 1337,
                    left: touches[t].pageX-50,
                    top: touches[t].pageY-50
                });
```

The code shouldn't lose track of the object and should be able to use multitouch.